# Connect node.js based socket.io WebSocket server from a C# program

Tags: c#, node.js, websocket, socket.io, websocket4net

I need to connect Node.js based WebSocket from a C# windows form code

Node module used https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io

I am using superwebsocket and WebSocket4Net

```
using SuperSocket.Common;
using SuperSocket.SocketBase;
using SuperSocket.SocketBase.Config;
using SuperSocket.SocketBase.Logging;
using SuperWebSocket;
using SuperWebSocket.SubProtocol;
using WebSocket4Net;

......
......

WebSocket webSocketClient = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/");
webSocketClient.Error += new EventHandler<SuperSocket.ClientEngine.ErrorEventArgs>(webSocketClient_Error);
webSocketClient.AllowUnstrustedCertificate = true;
webSocketClient.Opened += new EventHandler(webSocketClient_Opened);
webSocketClient.Closed += new EventHandler(webSocketClient_Closed);
webSocketClient.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>(webSocketClient_MessageReceived);
webSocketClient.Open();
```

But only **webSocketClient_Error** callback triggers always, can anyone help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Node.JS socket.io library uses a different URL pattern but you have given root URL, Please change your URL as follows then it should work

```
WebSocket webSocketClient = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket");
```

Comment: @ZigmaEmpire can you explain or give a pointer where this is explained please?

Comment: The URL is identified by practically executing the socket.io javascript client on a chrome browser and watching the network traffic screen provided by google chrome browser, there is no proper documentation for this