# Unity Chat application

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, chat, chatbot

i am currently working on a real-time chat app in Unity
and i found those platforms to work with,

Firebase : Can we send Videos efficiently ?? 
MatriX : https://www.ag-software.net/matrix-xmpp-sdk/
but i am not sure that we can send videos with [MatriX](https://www.ag-software.net/matrix-xmpp-sdk/) ?

i wanted to know from your experience 
what is the best way to make real-time chatting (support photos and videos sending) in Unity ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to find or create services where your clients can connect and:

1. upload files (photos, videos .etc) and get an public and downloadable URL.
2. send messages to other connected clients that apart from the string, also contain media metadata (.eg a list of file attachments which are actually URLs uploaded at service (1))

Now, if you cannot find a single service that supports those two then you could try to find two different ones.

[here](https://github.com/AngelKyriako/chat-dotnet-core) is an example of a chat console application in C#. It contains a web service and client library that is used by the console app. Instead of a console app, it could be used in a Unity app. It does not support file uploading but it can send messages between clients over web sockets.

If you were to create something yourself, instead of finding a 3rd party service, I would recommend node.js/express and socket.io for a server since its quite beginner friendly.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606053/connect-node-js-based-socket-io-websocket-server-from-a-c-sharp-program) is a C# client library that can listen to socket.io events from the server. It must be the same that is used in the console application I shared above.